# Allow <a> and <b> tags in PHP function?

Tags: php, html, tags, preg-replace, sanitization

I currently have use this function to clean inputs submitted by users:

```
// Cleaning input functions
function clean_Input($input) {
    $search = array(
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', // Strip out javascript
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si', // Strip out HTML tags
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU', // Strip style tags properly
        '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@' // Strip multi-line comments
    );
    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
}

function sanitize($input) {
    if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as $var => $val) {
            $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
        }
    } else {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }
        $input  = clean_Input($input);
        $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

However, I want to edit it so that it WILL allow `<a>` and `<b>` tags to pass through. Meaning it will accept links and bold tags, and WON'T remove them.

Currently, it removes all HTML tags including `<a>` tags and `<b>` tags, how can I change it to accomplish what I stated above?

If I knew how to work with the `preg_replace` function I would've tried something. However, I'm completely stuck, and have absoultely no idea where to go from here.

Comment: What's wrong with `strip_tags`?

Comment: This is not a job for regexen at all, HTML infamously cannot be handled properly using regexen. Use a library which is specialised for this purpose if you need to selectively sanitise HTML. The only one I know of that purportedly actually works for this purpose is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Make sure to read their comparison pages and background explanations to see exactly what complex topic you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong about using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), and passing it some  tags to allow, and therefore passthrough? Why Regex instead?

Consider the example on the manual page:

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Comment: The thing that's wrong with strip_tags is that it doesn't do *attribute sanitization* at all. Especially with links it's trivial to inject Javascript this way, which makes it virtually worthless.

Comment: So how about using a combination, allowing `<a>` and `<b>`, and afterwards validating the posted links with the function you started out with? By doing that, firstly you'll have a single responsibility for your linter function, and secondly you'll have way less regex processing, saving some performance.

Comment: *Regular expressions* are inherently unable to process *irregular languages* like HTML entirely correctly. This is the place for a tool which *understands* HTML rules, not for a pattern matcher. Maybe, *maybe* you can produce a regex complex enough to correctly match every single last permutation of HTML, but you'll get insane in the process and so will anyone having to maintain what you produced. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Didn't notice, you were not the OP. I see your point, and know that, but I suggested to reduce the regex to just validating the href of the links, as the OP wanted to kind of prevent posting scripts, but allow links. That reduces the complexity enormously, and shifts some responsibility to strip_tags.